# paypal login Authorization api return invalid_authz_code?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

When i try to login with Paypal. it rerun this.

```
401 Response: {"error":"invalid_authz_code","error_description":"Authorization Code is invalid"}
```

I am using sandbox api and account for login.
This is request URL.

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=code&state={STATE}&scope={SCOPE}
```

This is API call.

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the auth code has expired or was issued to a different client_id.

Sandbox & production client_ids are different, so make sure you're testing with the right client_id. You also need to [exchange the auth_code for an access token](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/identity/#token.authorizationcode.grant) before you can call the userinfo endpoint.